# What does _condition_ mean in metric?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-state-metrics

In [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/pod-metrics.md) there is a metric for pods - `kube_pod_status_ready` that has 3 attributes

```
pod=<pod-name>  
namespace=<pod-namespace> 
condition=<true|false|unknown>
```

What does `condition` attribute stand for? I can't find it's definition anywhere in the docs. I can guess what it means, but it would be great to get a definition or explanation of how it's calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's documented in the [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#podcondition-v1-core). In essence it's the condition in the `status` field for `"type": "Ready"` for a given pod. For example in the following output:

```
$ kubectl get pod <your-pod> -o=json | jq .status.conditions
[
  ...
  {
    "lastProbeTime": null,
    "lastTransitionTime": "2018-11-20T22:45:27Z",
    "status": "True",
    "type": "Ready"
  },
  ...
]
```

In this case, the sub-field `"status": "True"` represents `condition=true` in your metrics. Alternatively, `"status": "False"` would represent `condition=false` and `"status": "Unknown"` would represent `condition=unknown`.